# FormSpy - onChange with subscription on dirty is not showing values in input field

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form

We are using FormSpy, subscribed to dirty. OnChange function in the FormSpy will update the dirty tag in redux, when dirty is true. When I type in any input field, the first letter doesn't show up, but the redux state is updated with `dirty:true` on the first letter stroke.

Also form is written in a different file using

```
<Form
 component={Theform}
/>
```

This is how we used FormSpy

```
<FormSpy
  subscription={{ dirty: true }}
  onChange={state => this.updateDirty(state.dirty)}
  {...props}
/>

updateDirty(isDirty) {
  const { toggleIsDirty, dirtyState } = this.props;
  if (isDirty) {
    if (!dirtyState.isDirty) {
      toggleIsDirty();
    }
  }
}
```

When the `if (isDirty)` check is not done, it keeps updating the store value, but doesn't show anything in the input field.
Where did we go wrong?

**Update**:
I can't copy paste the actual code, but here is how it looks.

Action.js

```
const toggleDirty = () => ({
  type: types.TOGGLE_DIRTY,
});

export { toggleDirty };
```

Reducer.js

```
const dirtyState = (state = { isDirty: false}, { type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.TOGGLE__DIRTY: {
      return {
        isDirty: !state.isDirty,
      };
    }
    default: return state;
  }
};
```

Modal.jsx

```
class Modal extends Component {
  render () {
    const {storeValues} = this.props;
    const initialValues = {
      field1: storeValue.field1,
      field2: storeValue.field2
    }

    return {
      <Form 
        id="detailsForm"
        initialValues={initialValues}
        component={DetailsForm}
      />
    }
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = ({ storeValues }) => ({
  storeValues,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, null)(Modal);
```

DetailsForm.jsx

```
class DetailsForm extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.updateDirty = this.updateDirty.bind(this);
  }
  updateDirty(isDirty) {
    const { toggleIsDirty, dirtyState } = this.props;
    if (isDirty && !dirtyState.isDirty) {
      toggleIsDirty();
    }
  }

  render() {
    const {updateDirty} = this;
    const {
      intl, submitError, submitErrors, submitFailed, dirty, handleSubmit, form, errors, values, ...props
    } = this.props;
    return{
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} className="benefit-form">
        <FormSpy
          subscription={{ dirty: true }}
          onChange={state => updateDirty(state.dirty)}
          {...props}
        />
        <React.Fragment>
          <Input .... />
        </React.Fragment>
      </form>
    }
  }
}

const mapStateToProps = ({ dirtyState}) => ({
  dirtyState,
});

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
  toggleIsDirty() {
    dispatch(toggleDirty());
  },
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(DetailsForm);
```

When I type something like '123' in the input, only '23' is shown. When I type the first number, it just turns the `isDirty` flag to true in the store.
On debugging I found that updateDirty is called twice for the first character of the input - once with `isDirty` as true and again as false.

I put a consolelog in the onChange of FormSpy and it is triggered during the intial form load with `dirty` as false. And when I type in the first letter, it updates to true, action is dispatched and then immidiately gets triggered again with false. The letter is then not displayed. But from the second letter it acts normal. 
This works without any issues when I use local state and setState instead of dispatch.

We are using that flag to show up a modal when navigating away from the page with Dirty data.

Answer (score 0):

When you have state that is stored in multiple locations, and the state is updated by an event not built into React, you'll get the behaviour that your components are rendered multiple times, with data that might be conflicting, like in your case where the dirty states disagree. This re-renders will stop once the data becomes what you expect it to be, in your case the dirty states are the same.

**Option 1**

Only read the state from one of the stores. In your case, ignore what is passed by final forms, and read only from redux

**Option 2**

Find where the first non-react event is triggered, and wrap it in `unstable_batchedUpdate`